# Put Stop leak into engine. Can I reverse the process?

Tags: engine

I accidently poured Barsleaks stop leak for the radiator into the engine oil compartment. Is there any way I can reverse the process? The stuff is hardening already. This a 2004 Volvo S80.

Answer (score 10):

Open the drain plug immediately, go buy 10 quarts+ of oil. Let as much drain as it will, put the plug in, fill up with oil, run it until it's hot. You could even try that engine-cleaner additive that you add before changing. Drain it, change the oil filter, fill it again and run it. Change the oil again in about 100 miles.

Hope that the glue and sand hasn't worked its way into somewhere that it won't come out.

Then don't do it again.

Comment: Ow.  I feel really bad for this guy.  "Change the oil again in about 100 miles", for me, pretty much means "change the oil when you get home from work the next day".